# Create ViewModel inside ViewModel with IoC

Tags: wpf, mvvm, community-toolkit-mvvm

I am using the *CommunityToolkit.Mvvm* and *Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection*.
I need to create child ViewModels in a ViewModel as needed.

The Sub-ViewModel is registered with `services.AddTransient<SubViewModel>()`.
Is it a bad idea to create new instances with `IoC.Default.GetService<SubViewModel>()` directly from another ViewModel?
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Well it is better to use dependency injection and inject the instance (or a factory) via constructor. Using a magic dependency is the opposite of dependency injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is called *Abstract Factory* pattern.
If you need to create instances dynamically you usually inject factories.
Passing around the IoC container is a code smell. Because it defies the purpose of the Dependency Injection patter it is generally considered an anti-pattern.

If type construction is not too complex, you can avoid creating a factory class and inject a factory delegate instead (`Func<TNewInstanceType>`):

```cs
ServiceProvider container = new ServiceCollection()
  .AddSingleton<MainViewModel>()
  .AddTransient<SubViewModel>()

  // Register simple factory delgate without parameters
  .AddSingleton<Func<SubViewModel>>(serviceProvider => serviceProvider.GetService<SubViewModel>)

  // Register complex factory delegate with parameters.
  // This example creates a factory that requests a username parameter
  // to configure the new instance.
  .AddSingleton<Func<string, SubViewModel>>(serviceProvider => 
    username =>
    {
      SubViewModel newInstance = serviceProvider.GetService<SubViewModel>();
      newInstance.Username = username;
      return newInstance;
    })
  .BuildServiceProvider(new ServiceProviderOptions() { ValidateOnBuild = true });
```

Then declare the factory as constructor dependency and use the factory to create instances dynamically:

```cs
class MainViewModel
{
  private Func<SubViewModel> ParameterlessSubViewModelFactory { get; }
  private Func<SubViewModel> SubViewModelFactory { get; }

  public MainViewModel(Func<SubViewModel> parameterlessSubViewModelFactory, Func<SubViewModel> subViewModelFactory)
  {
    this.ParameterlessSubViewModelFactory = parameterlessSubViewModelFactory;
    this.SubViewModelFactory = subViewModelFactory;
  }

  private void CreateInstanceExample()
  {
     // Use the parameterless factory delegate
     SubViewModel newSubViewModel = this.ParameterlessSubViewModelFactory.Invoke();

     // Use the factory delegate that requires an argument which is used by the factory to configure the instance.
     SubViewModel configuredNewSubViewModel = this.SubViewModelFactory.Invoke("Teddy");
  }
}
```

Note, the first step to implement proper Dependency Injection is to implement the Dependency Inversion principle (the "D" in SOLID). In your case, you would have to define an `ISubViewModel` and register it with the concrete type `SubViewModel` as the service export:

```cs
// Register the service interface.
// Declare the dependencies in your code 
// using the interface type e.g. `ISubViewModel` instead of the concrete type e.g. `SubViewModel`.
.AddTransient<ISubViewModel, SubViewModel>()

// Define the ISubViewModel factory delegate. Because of the previous mapping, the factory will create the correct SubViewModel instance 
.AddSingleton<Func<ISubViewModel>>(serviceProvider => serviceProvider.GetService<ISubViewModel>)
```

```cs
class ViewModel
{
  private Func<ISubViewModel> SubViewModelFactory { get; }

  public ViewModel(Func<ISubViewModel> subViewModelFactory)
  {
    this.SubViewModelFactory = subViewModelFactory;
  }

  private void CreateInstanceExample()
  {
     ISubViewModel newSubViewModel = this.SubViewModelFactory.Invoke();
  }
}
```